# When to omit 'que' when discussing thinking (Pienso)

Tags: gramática

In my Spanish textbook it says that Spanish uses `que` when talking about thinking.

E.g. `Pienso que = I think that`

It then gives the following examples:

```
1) Pienso que puede hacerlo.
I think he can do it. 

2) Pienso que la elección fue muy emocionante
I think the election was very exciting.

3) I think large governments don't understand the public
Pienso que los altos gobernantes no entienden al pueblo

4) Pienso que este año vuelven a ganar la Copa.
I think this year they’ll win the Cup again.
```

But then it has the following examples:

```
5) Pienso irme la semana que viene o en dos semanas
I think go away next week or in two weeks

6) Pienso quedarme una semana en España
I think I’ll stay a week in Spain
```

Why do examples 5 and 6 omit the use of `que`? Is there are rule as to when to use `que` and when to omit it?

Answer (score 2):

"Pienso que" will be followed by a clause containing a tensed verb (*puede, fue, entienden, vuelven*).

Instead, in examples (5) and (6), "pienso" is followed by an infinitive and does not mean "believe" as in examples (1) to (4) but "plan to/intend to/consider the idea of".

Answer (score 1):

The examples you gave correspond to two different meanings of *pensar*. The first four employ the common pattern for when the meaning is **"to think"** and the object (the thing being thought) is a subclause. The basic difference with English here is that, in English, "that" is optional, while in Spanish *que* is compulsory.

The two examples without *que* show a slightly different meaning of *pensar*: here it's not "to think" but **"to plan"**, and what follows is not a subclause but an infinitive. In English you might translate is as "to be thinking [of/about]" or "to be planning on".

> *Pienso irme la semana que viene o en dos semanas.*
> "I'm planning on going away next week or in two weeks."
>
> *Pienso quedarme una semana en España.*
> "I'm thinking of staying a week in Spain."

It's more like "plan" than "think" actually, most times.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following pair, both sentences are correct:

> Pienso que iré mañana a tu casa.
>
> Pienso ir mañana a tu casa.

In both cases the subject is 'Yo', the verb is 'pensar' and the direct complement is a subordinate sentence.

The difference is that in the first subordinate sentence the verb is conjugated ('iré': first singular person of the indicative future), while in the second it uses an impersonal ('ir': infinitive).

Normally, the subordinate sentence is preceded by the pronoun 'que' or some similar conjunction. But if the subject of the main sentence ('*Yo* pienso') coincides with the subject of the subordinate sentence ('*Yo* iré'), then the conjunction 'que' is not used, and the verb is used in infinitive.

These are equivalent because the subject of the main and subordinate sentences are the same: 'tú'.

> No nades después de que comas.
>
> No nades después de comer.

But in the other hand, these are *not equivalent* because the subject of the main sentence is 'yo', and the subject of the subordinate is 'tú':

> Me gustaría que cantaras para nosotros.
>
> Me gustaría cantar para nosotros.

Comment: Both *pienso que iré* and *pienso ir* are correct though different in meaning. Please see my post or that of Pablodf's. Your remark about *que* being dropped when the subject in the main clause is the same as the one in the subordinate clause does not apply in this case.

Comment: @Gustavson: In the 6 examples proposed by the OP my approach is verified: (1) yo pienso / él puede (with 'que'); (2) yo pienso / la elección fue (with 'que'); (3) yo pienso / los gobernantes no entienden (with 'que'); (4) yo pienso / ellos vuelven (with 'que'); (5) yo pienso / yo me voy (without 'que'); (6) yo pienso / yo me quedo (without 'que').

Comment: What I find misleading is your assertion that when both subjects coincide *que* IS NOT used, as if this always held true. You should have said that *que* may be dropped (in which case the infinitive has to be used). With verbs denoting mental processes like *pensar, considerar, estimar, creer, esperar, sospechar*, etc. both patterns, with or without *que*, work fine when there is identity of subjects in the main and in the subordinate clause. With *pensar* we also have a change of meaning that should not be disregarded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "I think..." you must always say "que". When you use "pienso" + (infinitive) you talk about something you want to do. It's used in two cases: when you're talking rudely, for example, if you are threatening your interlocutor; and when you promise something.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta no hay una regla que aplique cuando debe o no ir el "que".

En el caso particular de las últimas dos oraciones si agregas "*que*" en "*Pienso que irme...*" debes colocar un complemento, porque con el "*que*" después de "*irme*" es como si dijeras que si te vas produce una determinada consecuencia que debes explicar dentro de la oración.

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

The first Pienso means "I believe" or "I think".

The second Pienso means "I have decided to ...".

As another example, to show the different meanings for the same word:

> Pienso que es culpa suya y no pienso ayudarle.
>
> I think (I believe) it is his/her fault, and I will not help him/her (I have decided to ... / I am determined to ...).

The first use reflects my opinion or my belief, and the second one reflects my will, my determination, my decision, what I will do, unless I change my mind.

As you can see in the corresponding  entry in the dictionary of the Real Academia Española:
http://dle.rae.es/?id=STY14i0|STayfGw
the verb "pensar" can have different meanings.

As for a rule for when to use "que": I would suggest you use it whenever you use the word "pienso" in the sense mentioned above.

Another example:

> ¿Vienes esta noche?
>   Are you coming tonight?
>
> Pienso que sí.
>   I think so.
>
> Pienso estar allí.
>   I'll be there.
>
> No pienso ir ni loca.
>   I'm not going at all. [she wouldn't go even if she had gone crazy]

Like the phrasal verbs in english, in this case I don't see a shortcut. The rule to apply could be quite general for the sudent of a foreign language: know the vocabulary (the word and its different meanings), study your grammar (use of "que" in compound sentences), and then read, hear and speak the word in different contexts.